# Unable to resolve "./useValue" from "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js"

Tags: react-native

The program run into an error code: 
`Unable to resolve "./useValue" from "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js"` 

I have tried to re-install the package using: npm install react-native-reanimated. 
Then, in the terminal it shows the following warning:

> Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently
> installed expo package version: 
> - react-native-reanimated - expected
> version range: ~1.9.0 - actual version installed: ^1.10.1 
> Your project
> may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the
> packages. To install the correct versions of these packages, please
> run: expo install [package-name ...]

Thus, I run the code as follow:
```expo install react-native-reanimated```, but still run into the error code. Please helppp. Thank you

Comment: Found working solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215154/react-native-reanimated-unable-to-resolve-usevalue (see the accepted answer).