# React-native-reanimated: Unable to resolve "./useValue"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to build a react native app. I have caught an error on the terminal saying

`Unable to resolve "./useValue" from "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js"`

I reinstalled react-native-reanimated to the expected version range.

`Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:

- react-native-reanimated - expected version range: ~1.9.0 - actual version installed: ^1.10.1
  Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages. To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]`

Thus, I run the code as follow: `npm install react-native-reanimated@1.9.0`, but still run into the error code.

I could realy use some help on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try uninstalling the package ==> close ide (all instances) ==> open the ide ==> install the package again ==> run "expo start -c"

Comment: I already did that... I even removed react-native-reanimated completly and reinstalled the 1.9.0 version

Comment: try: uninstalling the package ==>  close ide (all instances) ==> open the ide ==> install the package again ==> run "expo start -c"

Comment: It worked, thank you very mutch! What is the difference between "expo start -c" and simply "expo start" on the cmd?

Comment: Works like a charm! Tnx.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, clearing cache, deleting node-mod's/package-lock etc - even stepped it back to version `react-native-reanimated: 1.7.0` - still no luck. I am being advised this file is missing: `node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/Animated.js` - checked node modules after each install and it's not there. Weird.

Comment: After uninstalling the package and before closing ide's try the 'npm prune' command

Answer (score 4):

Only do this:

```
expo start --clear
```

From Expo Documentation at [Expo Start command](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/expo-cli/#expo-start).

`--clear, -c | Clear the React Native Packager cache.`

Comment: This command was sufficient for the same issue I have as the OP. Perhaps @ATQSHL can update this answer with the reason why `--clear` flag solves the problem or what that flag does?