# React Native Getting this error 'Unrecognized operator abs'

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

[image]

Getting this error when adding react-navigation-drawer to my expo project, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Faced this error few days back, I was able to fix it by running:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Comment: Tried that able to fix the above error but getting a new error Unable to resolve "./useValue" from "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js"

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215154/react-native-reanimated-unable-to-resolve-usevalue this will fix your error

Comment: Additonally, after installing the correct packages, I cleared the expo cache using `expo start -c` and cleared the cache on my iOS device by opening the simulator Device > Erase All Content and Settings. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @GoskulaJayachandra what made you decide to fix "unrecognized operator abs" by installing the packages react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view ?

Answer (score 4):

It is library version issue.
Don't use 'yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated'
It will add  react-native-reanimated@1.13.0
react-native-gesture-handler@1.7.0

Use 'expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated'
It will add react-native-gesture-handler@~1.6.0 react-native-reanimated@~1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Close your IDE. Restart your computer.
 Open your project, re-install you package (**npm install**).
 re-run your project (**react-native run-android**)

Comment: This answer is too general to address the problem and does not provide much benefit to those seeking a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because some of your installed packages are not matched with current version of **Expo**

In your terminal you will see a warning like

- expo-av - expected version range: ~8.2.1 - actual version installed: ~8.7.0
- expo-constants - expected version range: ~9.1.1 - actual version installed: ~9.3.3

To solve this issue you have to update all the packages according to the current expo version by running this command

```
expo install packageName@packageVersion   // expo install expo-av@8.2.1
```