# Unrecognized operator abs

Tags: android, react-native, expo

when I run the project the error, UNRECOGNIZED OPERATOR ABS was appears in expo.
I also run "expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view" but it didn't resolve.

Comment: does this helps? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315761/react-native-getting-this-error-unrecognized-operator-abs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Getting this error 'Unrecognized operator abs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315761/react-native-getting-this-error-unrecognized-operator-abs)