# React Native Getting this error 'Operator "abs" not found'

Tags: react-native, build, react-native-reanimated

I have a project I am working on that built yesterday. Today, I am getting this error 'Operator "abs" not found' as seen in the screenshot below. I am not using `expo` as the build system though the project does use react-native-reanaminated which keeps coming up in my search for a solution and also in this answer [React Native Getting this error 'Unrecognized operator abs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315761/react-native-getting-this-error-unrecognized-operator-abs).

I tried the solutions there to no avail. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```sh
❯ npx react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.7
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
    Memory: 359.10 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.1.2 - /usr/local/bin/fish
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.4.0 - /var/folders/rt/7lc5vcw16459dszl8djk35fh0000gn/T/fnm-shell-146260/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - ~/Github/project5/app/node_modules/.bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.8 - /var/folders/rt/7lc5vcw16459dszl8djk35fh0000gn/T/fnm-shell-146260/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.7, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 11.7/11E801a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: javac 15 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^3.0.4 => 3.2.1
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found

❯ qnm react-native-gesture-handler
react-native-gesture-handler
└── 1.8.0

❯ qnm react-native-reanimated
react-native-reanimated
└── 1.13.1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by running the following commands.
The first command cleans the ios build in app/ios directory.
The second command resets the simulator. You can also do it from the GUI by clicking `Erase All Content and Settings`.[image]

```sh
❯ cd ios && xcodebuild clean
❯ killall "Simulator" 2> /dev/null; xcrun simctl erase all
```

Then you rebuild your app as normal with `react-native start` and open you simulator.